# How to fix the issue of the code getting stuck unless the kernel is restarted prior to every run?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this tkinter code. When running my code the first time in jupyter notebook, the code runs great. If I try to run the code again without restarting the kernel the code will get stuck at this tkinter section. Although the window appears and allows me to choose my option from the dropdown menu, the selection is never output-ed and the code gets stuck.

**What should I change to allow the code to run through every time, without having to restart the kernel?**

```
from tkinter import *

OPTIONS = [
"Physician 1",
"Physician 2",
"Physician 3"
]

master = Tk()
master.title("Physician Name")
master.geometry('300x200')
master['bg'] = '#add8e6'

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

def ok():
    global name
    name =variable.get()
    print (name)
    master.destroy()

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Jupyter Notebook is not really good for GUIs, it is good at machine learning and data etc...

Comment: i see. so the issue is probably jupyter not the code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I tested it and it worked fine. As PCM mentioned, it could be that Jupyter Notebooks are not very good for GUIs. If I were you, I would try on a different computer. I would have written a comment for this but my reputation is not up to it yet.

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: if you will try to run it on Jupyter on server - like Google Colab - then it will not work because `Tkinter` will try to display on monitor connected directly to server, not on your local monitor - so you will not see tkinter window. There will be even worst because servers don't need monitors and they don't have installeed GUIs (XWindows) so tkinter will raise error.